# Apache script config with loggly

Tags: apache, loggly

I am trying to configure [loggly](https://www.loggly.com/docs/sending-apache-logs/) in apache in my ubuntu machine.
What I have done is

```
curl -O https://www.loggly.com/install/configure-apache.sh
sudo bash configure-apache.sh -a XXXXXX -u XXXXXX
```

After entering the last line it's saying

```
ERROR: Apache logs did not make to Loggly in time. Please check network and firewall settings and retry.
Manual instructions to configure Apache2 is available at https://www.loggly.com/docs/sending-apache-logs/. Rsyslog troubleshooting instructions are available at https://www.loggly.com/docs/troubleshooting-rsyslog/
```

Any idea why it's showing and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a network issue or a delay in sending the logs or even an issue  with the script. Check out the following link that has the manual instructions. https://www.loggly.com/docs/sending-apache-logs/ that you can follow and use to verify the script created the configuration files correctly.

Comment: I have tried manual and automatic script both script.Nothing has solved.Do you know any other process to detect the actual problem

Comment: The same problem =(